# Jetpack Compose props typing

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking for an elegant way to type Composable functions parameters. I'm used to React, where you pass a single `props` parameter without having to have a million of them.

For reference, what is the cleanest way to to something like this

```
interface MyCompProps {
   foo: string
   bar: number
} 

function MyComp(props: MyCompProps) {...}
```

with Compose?

Do I have to create a class and instantiate one when I build the props? Do I use maps? Is it the wrong way of thinking about it?

Right now I'm doing something like

```
class ProjectListItemProps(
    val imageUrl: String,
    val projectName: String,
    val createdAt: String
)

@Composable
fun ProjectListItem(props: ProjectListItemProps) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Android it's recommended to create data classes to represent data objects as entities.

For example, in a notes app you would create a note data class as following:

```
data class Note(
    var id: String = "",
    var dateAdded: Long = 0,
    var title: String = "",
    var textContent: String = "",
    var isFavorite: Boolean = false,
)
```

Then in compose you can create a composeable that represents the note in the UI:

```
@Composable
fun Note(note: Note){
    //child composables
}
```

But if the parameters don't represent an entity, such as whether to show ProgressBar or not, you shouldn't put it in a class.

And remember, in Kotlin you can use default parameters, then when you call the function you pass a parameter only when you want to pass a value different from the default one.

Example:

```
@Composable
fun Page(showProgressBar: Boolean = false){
    //child composables
}
```

If you called Page without passing any parameters it won't show the progress bar, because `showProgressBar = true` by default. But if want to show it you pass `true` to override the default value:

```
Note() /*progress bar is hidden.*/
Note(showProgressBar = true) /*progress bar is shown*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to check out the design of the `Composables` provided by the framework.
For example:

```
LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
) {
    // ...
}
```

So in short, yes it is a good idea, and I'd use it for grouping attributes.